# PHP - Session identifier - Security

Tags: php, security, session, ssl, session-variables

I have a question about using the global `$_SESSION[]` variable.

As of right now for my web-application whenever a user logs in, a row that matches that username and that specific password is returned. I then get the column `user_hash` and store that `user_hash` in the `$_SESSION['id']`.

I use this session to recognize which user has logged in and perform database queries based on this unique hash. I read somewhere that having a "static" identifier like this (the static identifier being the user_hash, as it never changes) is unsafe, and that I should rather have the user_hash change dynamically.

So I implemented a system where everytime a user logged and/or navigated to some other page within the web-application, I would generate a new hash, store it in the database, and then store it in the global `$_SESSION['id']` variable. I managed to do this, but now everytime someone tries to log in from two devices, the device with the "older" session is invalid, because the user_hash changed from the new device and logs off the user with an older session.

My question is, is there really any point in doing this? I am using ssl (https) for my webserver, so session hijacking is relatively off the table I think? If there is a security flaw by only having a static session identifier, is there a better way to make it dynamic, while on the same time not logging the other user off?

Comment: with https it's still possible to session hijack, cross site script or sql inject

Comment: @RaymondNijland although session hijacking would normally require malware in the user's browser when using TLS and that's really not something web sites can easily protect against.  If you're transferring your session ID over https, it's not subject to man in the middle attacks which is the common form of session hijacking.

Comment: @Devon i mean with session hijack that the attacker is bruteforcing session_id's to find a valid one that a user is using.... the defualt PHP session handling isn't very secure

Comment: Here's a quick read about a discussion on this with Laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15252.  It short, you can perform application logic to require a password for important things (deleting something, accessing account details, etc) but https is the best protection against hijacking.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I guess that would depend on the hash.  If we're talking about something like 128-bit or greater, that would take a very long time to brute force, especially over the internet.

Comment: please use paragraphs. Clumps of text like that is very hard to read. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two Useful Links**:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions

https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions

---

> *I managed to do this, but now everytime someone tries to log in from two devices, the device with the "older" session is invalid, because the user_hash changed from the new device and logs off the user with an older session.*

While this may be nessecary depending on your security requirements, the [first link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions) I posted above says this:

> mark the old session as obsolete and mark it to expire in ten seconds [or some time that suits your needs]. This way any queued up requests will still have access to the expired session but we don’t have to leave it open forever.

```
static function regenerateSession()
{
    // If this session is obsolete it means there already is a new id
    if(isset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']) || $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] == true)
        return;

    // Set current session to expire in 10,30,100 seconds etc.
    $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 10; //or 30 seconds or whatever.

    // Create new session without destroying the old one
    session_regenerate_id(false);

    // Grab current session ID and close both sessions to allow other scripts to use them
    $newSession = session_id();
    session_write_close();

    // Set session ID to the new one, and start it back up again
    session_id($newSession);
    session_start();

    // Now we unset the obsolete and expiration values for the session we want to keep
    unset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']);
    unset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']);
}
```

---

> *So I implemented a system where everytime a user logged and/or navigated to some other page within the web-application, I would generate a new hash, store it in the database, and then store it in the global $_SESSION['id'] variable.*

On a personal note I would suspect it is extremely in-efficient and will cause you a large overhead of server load this constant reinvention. It is just not needed.

If you really want to reinvent the session, simply use `session_regenerate_id()` and set it to a time value (say every 10 minutes), as [outlined in the first link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions), at the top of this post.

The only value that goes over the wire, that matters, is the session identification all values within the session array **are never seen by the browser or the end user**.

So; as long as your session id is a **LONG** randomised value, it hides in plain sight. From the [second link above](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions) for more destails about how to ensure PHP gives you much more random and longer named session ids.

*php.ini*:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.cookie_domain = "example.com"
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.entropy_length = 32
session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.hash_function = sha256
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

*If storing sessions in a database please do ensure that you make your column names for the session id long enough, else sessions will never connect due to truncation of the session name.*

---

**Some other factors**:

- Do ensure that your session cookies are set as `encrypted` by PHP. This has to be manually done regardless of the state of your TLS connection. see `session.cookie_secure=1`, above.
- You can help minimise the already unlikely event of hjacking by adding in browser or ip specific data (such as a hash of these respective `$_SERVER` values) to compare when carrying out tasks that warrent double checking the session, to compare that the browser type/client IP still compares to what's in the session record. There can be issues with each of these two approaches, such as a minority of people on mobile connections may change IP during login or users on multiple devices probably will have different browsers on each, but find a methodology to compare as you need *(This is also referenced in the [first link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions) at the top of the page)*.
- As stated above, the `$_SESSION` data is never stored on the client machine, so hashing values from the Database to store in the `$_SESSION` is very probably above and beyond your security needs.
- The (single) most important thing is that the session id is secured and large enough to comfortably accommodate a potential hacker fishing with fake session ids as a kin to playing battleships on minecraft

Comment: Thank-you! Great answer!

Comment: @tomSurge glad to hear it. Which parts informed you the most? any parts things you already knew?